# Keep getting some permission denied error

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I keep getting some permission denied error, what is that?

Every time when I am trying to install anything, the same permission denied error message I get in python, in nltk tool

> error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nameparser': Permission denied ---------------------------------------- Cleaning up... Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip_build_vandana/nameparser/setup.py';exec(compile(getatt‌​r(tokenize, 'open', open)(file).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), file, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-4Rd7GE-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_vandana/nameparser Storing debug log for failure in /home/vandana/.pip/pip.log

Comment: You'll have to include the full error message in your post, together with the command(s) that cause it.

Comment: This might be overly simplistic, but maybe try `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably doing `python setup.py install something` or `pip install something` and its trying to install to the global Python package location, for which your user does not have access. You need to use [virtual environments](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).